Powershell Get-AzRoleAssignment ISSUE
$resourceGroupName = "az-dna-xxxxx-test"

$roleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
 
foreach ($assignment in $roleAssignments) {

    Write-Host "DisplayName: $($assignment.DisplayName)"

    Write-Host "Role Definition Name: $($assignment.RoleDefinitionName)"

    Write-Host "Scope: $($assignment. Scope)"

}

getting blank value for displayname is there any value i have to put in to get display name value
output is
DisplayName        : 
RoleDefinitionName : Monitoring Contributor
Scope              : /providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/xxxxx

help me get display name value in output

Have you tried adding -Property @("DisplayName") to have it fetch that property? And in some cases -ConsistencyLevel eventual is required.

@jessehouwing yes but still blank value

The DisplayName has no values so you cannot get something that does not exist.

Check if those users or ServicePrincipal is present or not, for them DisplayName will not show Ref. PowershellScript

There are multiple security groups and users as well but unable to get display name or principal name

Same Snippet is worked in my enviornment.

yes but i'm getting blank value even if group or serviceprincipal present

If you are getting null values in the display name, run the command individually instead of in a loop, as shown below, and share the output result image for more clarification Get-AzRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalName "http://testapp1.com"

Do you find users here : https://imgur.com/AZfhfhu.png

https://imgur.com/a/jXhpY97 please see the image for indiviual yes there are users spn groups as well

Can u pls add portal image where is users is present

How can you get a value that is blank.  If DisplayName has no value you will never get the value.

My script is to get role assignment details of a resource group without any name   how users will be given access ? if you can see my screenshot above some have contributor access some have reader access i just want to get the name of spn user or group which has what acccess to the resource

I basically want these details to fetched for a resource group in powershell https://imgur.com/a/2c3TGNm

Use this command Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName <RG Name> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Displayname

doesn't return any value

What error message you are getting, after running this command  Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName <RG_Name>| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Displayname

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78300737/15339544 its either permissions or the object assigned to that role doesn't exist anymore

doesn't return any value@PratikJadhav

spn should have what type of access?

SPN should have atleast Reader access.

It had read access but just not getting dispaly name alone

Could you try granting Directory.Read.All permission to the Service Principal? Refer this SO thread

https://imgur.com/a/ZNbTIuk trying to add line display value as null in the script but that is also not working

Did you refered this SO_Thread

Can you try once in cloudShell?


DisplayName        :
RoleDefinitionName : Monitoring Contributor
Scope              : /providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/xxxxx

As this error, encounters because of the Identity of the  users, groups or Service Principal will not found in that RG like below:

Here, role and scope subscription is present Owner but Identity is not found.
To resolve this error, Ensure that Identity must be found like below:

Note: For enabling the Managed Identity to retrieve information from the Role Assignments, need to  assign or grant the necessary API permission such as Directory.Read.All will allow your Managed Identity to query any principal in Entra ID. On other hand, for detailed access of users, you can grant User.Read.All for user information only, and so on
Use below powershell code snippet:
$resourceGroupName = "<Resource Group Name>"

try {
  # Get role assignments for the resource group
  $roleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

  # Iterate through each assignment
  foreach ($assignment in $roleAssignments) {
    # Display DisplayName (if available)
    Write-Host "DisplayName: $($assignment.DisplayName)"

    # Handle missing DisplayName gracefully
    if ($assignment.DisplayName -eq $null) {
      Write-Warning "DisplayName not available, using Id instead."
      Write-Host "Id: $($assignment.DisplayName)"
    }

    # Display Role Definition Name and Scope
    Write-Host "Role Definition Name: $($assignment.RoleDefinitionName)"
    Write-Host "Scope: $($assignment.Scope)"
  }
}
catch {
  # Handle potential errors during retrieval
  Write-Error "Error retrieving role assignments: $_"
  
}


Here, If both displayName and object_id of the object is null which means object is not exist.
Output:

Reference:
SO-Thread by Santiago Squarzon
